# DJango join on two fields

Tags: python, sql, django

Basically I have three models in django:

```
Car(models.Model):
   id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
   company_id = models.ForeignKey(Company, models.DO_NOTHING)
   type_id = models.ForeignKey(CarType, models.DO_NOTHING)'

CarType(model.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)

Vendor(model.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(Company, models.DO_NOTHING)
    type_id = models.ForeignKey(CarType, models.DO_NOTHING)
    vendor_priority = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
```

i also have the code

```
my_cars = Car.objects.filter(cars_filter)
```

What I wish to do is to join the information from ventor to my_cars so that I could access the vendor_priority information, I would have to create a join on type_id and company_id, keeping my existing filters. In SQL what I want to do would akin to:

```
select * from cars left join vendor on cars.company_id = vendor.company_id 
and cars.type_id = vendor.type_id 
where cars_filter = cars_filter;
```

Comment: What datebase are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it like this:**

```
query = Car.objects.filter(cars_filter).annotate(vendor_priority=Subquery(Vendor.objects.filter(company_id=OuterRef('company_id'), type_id=OuterRef('type_id')).values('vendor_priority')[:1])) #ensure only first value is fetched (if any)
```

***Adjust column name if necessary.***